# weird typing mismatch c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I am not sure why I am getting this error when in the .h files it was defined that format was a Parser*. The compiler tells me that in the method Parser::changeformat(int) I cannot convert an int* to a Parser* pointer(the cpp files aren't done yet so please ignore all the other methods if they throw errors or look weird). Why is this happening and how can I fix it. This may have something to do with inheritance so I'll point out a subclass of parser that would fit. Also, in any case if you have suggestions about other parts then be my guest.

Parser.h

```
#ifndef PARSER_H_
#define PARSER_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

/*
 * This is a parser for reading and writing files
 * it takes in an integer for the file type it should read
 * or none if you would like to change it later and reuse
 * the parser
 */

class Parser {

public:
Parser();
Parser(int);
virtual ~Parser();
void open();
bool open(std::string&);
bool read();
bool write();
bool close();
void changeformat(int);
private:

    int filetype = -1;
    Parser* format = 0;
};

#endif /* PARSER_H_ */
```

Parser.cpp

```
#include "Parser.h"

Parser::Parser()
{
    filetype = -1;
}
Parser::Parser(int filetype)
{
    switch(filetype)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            //load xml format via instantiating xmlpar subclass and overloading methods
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            //load txt format
            break;
        }
    }

}

Parser::~Parser()
{
    if(this->format)
    delete this->format;// TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

//the classes below are to be overloaded with a subclass's own method

void Parser::open()
{
    return;
}
bool Parser::open(std::string& filename)
{

    if(this->format->open(filename))
    {
        std::cout<<"OK: "+filename+" opened\n";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: "+filename+" unable to be opened\n";
        return false;
    }
}
bool Parser::read()
{
    //make failure checks for all past open in this cpp
    return this->format->read();
}
bool Parser::write()
{

    return this->format->write();
}
bool Parser::close()
{


    return this->format->close();
}
void Parser::changeformat(int)
{
    switch(filetype)
    {
        case -1:
            break;
        case 0:
        {
            this->format = new xmlpar();
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            //load txt format
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

xmlpar.h

```
/*
 * xmlpar.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 22, 2015
 *      Author: root
 */

#ifndef XMLPAR_H_
#define XMLPAR_H_

#include "Parser.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class xmlpar: public Parser{
public:
    xmlpar();
    virtual ~xmlpar();
    bool open(std::string&);//opens a stream and checks association
    bool read(std::fstream&);//creats dom tree and hands it forward via reference
    bool write(std::fstream&);//edits domtree but does not write to the physical file
    bool close(std::fstream&);//the dom tree is flushed, the fstream associated to the file is closed and everyone is happy... I think
private:
    std::fstream *file= 0;
    bool flush();//write dom tree in memory to physical file
};

#endif /* XMLPAR_H_ */
```

xmlpar.cpp

```
/*
 * xmlpar.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 22, 2015
 *      Author: root
 */

#include "xmlpar.h"

xmlpar::xmlpar()
{

}

bool xmlpar::open(std::string& filename)
{
    file = new std::fstream(filename, std::ios::in|std::ios::out);
    return file->good();

}
bool xmlpar::close(std::fstream &file)
{
    this->write(file);
    file->close();
    //write failcheck here
}
xmlpar::~xmlpar() {
    this->close(file);
}
```

Comment: `Parser.cpp` doesn't seem to `#include "xmlpar.h"` or know about the type `xmlpar` in any other way...

Comment: Why are you writing an XML parser when there are many free libraries out there, *that have already been debugged*.

Comment: If you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help), you'll probably discover the problem along the way.

Comment: BTW, please refrain from the `this->` syntax as it is not necessary.  Change the names of your parameters or your member variables.

Comment: Add `const` to parameters that you are not going to change, such as the filename in your `open` method.

Comment: ah ... ok thanks for the suggestions. as far as why i'd want to do it, i'd rather make one on my own just to practice my skills on c++.@ThomasMatthews Also why not this->

Comment: @Angew I wouldn't need that cause its a pointer to a parser right? Not a subclass of parser.

Comment: @swiftsword94 But without including the header, the compiler has no way of knowing that `xmlpar` is a class derived from `Parser`. So it does not know how to assign a `xmlpar*` to a `Parser*` (not to mention the fact that it should also error out on not knowing the name `xmlpar`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate an instance of `xmlpar` that is derived from `Parser` base class without including headers of derived class `xmlpar` at `Parser.cpp`. The compiler is not finding definition for `xmlpar` here:

```
this->format = new xmlpar();
```

I also doubt this is a good practice.